# Xamarin.iOS on the Mac Server is not compatible

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am using **VS 2017 RC**,
When i open new project --> `Cross-Platform\Cross Platform App`
I get error;

> The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 10.2) on the Mac Unnamed Server (...) is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS 10.4.

Comment: You have mismatch `Xamarin.iOS` versions installed. Both installations on the Mac and Windows need to match. Upgrade your Mac from Xamarin.iOS `10.2`. to `10.4`

Comment: OK, thanks. I updated Xamarin.IOS alpha mode updates, then fixed

Answer (score 1):

As it's mentioned in the comments, this happens when Xamarin.iOS versions mismatch on Windows and Mac.

VS 2017 RC is bundled with Alpha versions of Xamarin tools. Make sure that you have Xamarin.iOS alpha installed on the Mac as well